# Batch.end() vs Batch.flush() libgdx

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx

I am a little confused guessing the difference bw Batch.flush() vs Batch.end()

- Is one more efficient than other
- When and how should flush be used
- Any other important detail about flush

Answer (score 1):

public void end()
Finishes off rendering. Enables depth writes, disables blending and texturing. Must always be called after a call to Batch.begin()

public void flush()
Causes any pending sprites to be rendered, without ending the Batch.

Personally, I can't see any reason to call flush() instead of end().

Comment: Example code for Clipping, with the use of scissorstack https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/2d/clipping-with-the-use-of-scissorstack , contains flush() method